# When I try to play a not-playable youtube video, Youtube Player endless loading in android

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

When I try to play a not-playable youtube video,
the youtube player displays an infinite loading
I want to display a screen that fits the errorReason of onError method like PC youtube

I want
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5oh9.png)

but, Youtube Player in Android
[Loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foiE9.jpg)

Comment: May you share us a YouTube video id that is not-playable ?

Comment: Please, provide a piece of code where you're trying to play a video. Current question doesn't provide any information to deal with.

Comment: not-playable youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxQ9e7EiWbo

Comment: and my code just
youtubePlayer.cueVideo(youtubeId)